# Sending ajax POST data to controller

Tags: controllers, ajax, post-data

This is my ajax request:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".emailfocusout").focusout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/checkout/Email/Email',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'email': 'che607@yahoo.com'},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('SUCCESS: ', data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('ERROR: ', data);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function EmailAction()
{
    // TODO: Implement me!  Here are some hints ;-)

    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    var_dump($email);
    echo $email;
}
```

I can't save - data: {'email': 'che607@yahoo.com'} - to -  `$email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');`

What am I doing wrong?

*** UPDATE - SOLVED ***
I took data out of the ajax request.  And in URL I put:

```
url: '/checkout/Email/Email/email/me@example.com',
```

I worked like that.

Comment: can you please upload your model file or database install script?

Comment: Do you getting data in controller?

Answer (score 0):

just use only

```
data: 'email=me@example.com',
```

and if you want to send dynamic email value use

```
data:'email='+$("input[name='email']").val(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
    $.ajax({
                        url: '/checkout/Email/Email',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {'email': 'che607@yahoo.com'},
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log('SUCCESS: ', data);
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            console.log('ERROR: ', data);
                        },
                    });
```

to

```
    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/checkout/Email/Email',
                        data: {'email': 'che607@yahoo.com'},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log('SUCCESS: ', data);
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            console.log('ERROR: ', data);
                        },
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller file you can try follow code.

$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$email = $postData['email'];